# Would a question about the history of the French word 'familier' be on-topic for this SE?

Tags: discussion

Is a question asking about "the real-world circumstances surrounding the historical association of 'familier' (French) with the concept of Magical Familiars, centuries ago," on topic for this SE?

[Question stemmed from this](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/631?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm leaning towards yes, but I'm about the most permissive user on this stack, so a "lean" from me is probably not a good sign.

Basically, I think you are on good ground if you ask where the concept came from in Western folklore (or if we even know that).